# C# Entity Framework Core - One-To-Many relationship - {"Invalid object name 'xxx'."} Exception

Tags: c#, one-to-many, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create the simplest one-to-many relationship that is possible.
(Test record that has many tests stored inside list)

Unfortunately when I try to execute:

```
TestContext con = new TestContext();
var rec = con.TestRecords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SomeK1 == "aaa");
```

I receive this exception:

```
{"Invalid object name 'TestRecords'."}
```

This is how my class looks like:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TestRecord> TestRecords { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //string connectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Asmodat_FxTrader_Data.TestDb.v26;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\asmodat\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Asmodat FxTrader\Asmodat FxTrader Data\FxTraderTicks.mdf"";Integrated Security=True";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var tr = modelBuilder.Entity<TestRecord>();
            tr.ToTable("TestRecords");
            //tr.HasMany(p => p.Tests).WithOne(x => x.TestRecord).HasForeignKey(p => p.TestRecordId);

            var t = modelBuilder.Entity<Test>();
            t.HasOne(p => p.TestRecord).WithMany(p => p.Tests).HasForeignKey(p => p.TestRecordId);
            t.ToTable("Tests");
        }
    }


    public class TestRecord
    {
        public TestRecord()
        {
            this.Tests = new List<Test>();
        }

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TestRecordId { get; set; }

        public string SomeK1 { get; set; }

        public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TestId { get; set; }

        public int TestRecordId { get; set; }

        public TestRecord TestRecord { get; set; }


        public string SomeResult { get; set; }
        public long SomeDuration { get; set; }
    }
```

I just can't make it work, and don't understand what is wrong with my class. Could anyone point me to some directions, how can I solve my problem ?

Comment: It means that `TestRecords` is not the name of the table in your database. You have to specify the correct name in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @GertArnold I added: tr.ToTable("TestRecords"); as well as t.ToTable("Tests"); nothing changed, still the same error.

Comment: Well, you didn't change anything essentially because you still use the same table names. The question is: what are the table names in the database?

Comment: There are none, when I execute: 'Add-Migration Test -Context TestContext' and then 'Update-Database -Context TestContext' (it compiles without errors in console manager) but database contains only: __EFMigrationsHistory table and nothing else. I thought that these tables will appear only after first save: 'con.SaveChanges();'. Isn't it like this ?

Comment: It appears to be connectionstring problem. I tried to add table to existing database - .mdf file that I added to the project. Does anyone have idea how can this be changed so adding table to existing database is possible ?